# Membership provider getting role history

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I had a requirement where let's say for Application "A1" i had roles "R1", "R2" for a user.
Now I want to update the roles for application A1 to roles R1, R2, R3 for the same  user.
But I want to maintain history of all role changes to all user.

Comment: the question is . . . ?

Comment: Hi, my question is how to do the above, like how to get role history if some one roles are updated or deleted in Membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get role history if some one roles are updated or deleted in
>   Membership provider.

You cannot add or remove a column inside Role table. Membership Provider does not allow modifying of its table.

You need to have a separate table to keep track of the history.